# Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, Не могу установить расширения

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Установил я эту студию новую, и что-то не могу понять чего она хочет, пробовал разные расширения, ставлю прямо с менеджера через поиск, получаю ошибку в логе:

`System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation, Version=15.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation, Version=15.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`

Есть варианты как это пофиксить? И почему, вроде бы самая тривиальная функциональность сразу же после установки тупо не работает? Может зря я обновился? Старая 2013я работала всегда адекватно с расширениями и всем остальным, а тут ничего не трогая чистая установка с коробки и такая проблема...

Comment: Во общем. Получается либо я либо инсталятор удалил пакеты установочные, по пути `c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\` Из-за этого не ставились расширения, пока буду разбираться еще, что это за пакеты и можно ли их как то удалить или они нужны для работы. Но пока что с ними все работает нормально.